# Group Stage in AngularJS sorting by rank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry, I'm learning Angular yet,

I need dev a group stage that is sort by rank (like image below) but your rank is based in yours WINS and LOSES.

[image]

I don't how I can do it. =/

Here is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5YtEBjFDjEQ14YXdhii?p=preview

```
app.controller('marshalLeagueCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.groups = {
        groups: [
            {
                name: "GRUPO A",
                teams: [
                    { 
                        name: "Time 1",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 2",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 3",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 4",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "GRUPO B",
                teams: [
                    { 
                        name: "Time 1",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 2",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 3",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 4",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "GRUPO C",
                teams: [
                    { 
                        name: "Time 1",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 2",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 3",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 4",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "GRUPO D",
                teams: [
                    { 
                        name: "Time 1",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 2",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 3",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Time 4",
                        link: "http://www.google.com",
                        wins: 5,
                        loses: 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
});

<section class="container group-stage league-page" ng-controller="marshalLeagueCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2>Group Stage</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="group-area col-sm-6" ng-repeat="group in groups.groups">
                        <div class="group-box col-sm-12">
                            <h3 class="rank-header">{{group.name}}</h3>
                            <div class="row rank-labels">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">RANK</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">V</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">D</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row rank-team" ng-repeat="team in group.teams">
                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">1</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <a href="{{team.link}}">{{team.name}}</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">{{team.wins}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">{{team.loses}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With angular filters!

Loop through the array and add a property to the array, determining whatever the ranking is. You could also create a custom filter, but I'm assuming you're going to want to display the ranking number elsewhere. Create the function below, and use a for loop to loop through the data structure, analyzing your data and attaching a ranking number.

```
$scope.addRank = function(person){..../////ranking code here////.....}
```

So the ranking will end up looking something like this.

```
{ 
    name: "Time 4",
    link: "http://www.google.com",
    wins: 5,
    loses: 2,
    ranking: 4,
    //or any number that is determined by your algorithm
}
```

Once you have that property, it's a simple feat for angular to sort your data using filters! Use the orderBy filter. Filters take care of how you display data you get from controllers.

```
<div class="group-area col-sm-6" ng-repeat="group in groups.groups | orderBy: 'rank'">
```

Don't forget the quotation marks around rank!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the orderBy filter. `ng-repeat="team in group.teams | orderBy:'wins'"`